# How to save field form in database with required fields

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm figuring how to save the field entered into database when there's no field required left.

I can already save from database with php and mysqli, but I don't want to include the null/blank value from the database which is why I'm using required field but I don't know how to use it. What I wanted to do is when all the required field is not null or has already value in it, it will gonna save from the database.

I don't know what to put on 
         form method=post action="HERE"

PS: Sorry for bad english.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>


<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `action=""` you should point to the php file that is gonna do the back-end job. (getting the datas, checking the inputs, and storing into the database).

like this `action="file.php"`

to check whether an input is correctly filled, you have many ways of doing so :

```
`<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" required>`
```

(html5)

you can do it serverside ( in your php file )

`if(!isset($_POST['name'))` OR  `if(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) !== 0)` OR `if($_POST['name'] !== '')`

and many other ways.

Hope this was what you were searching for!

Comment: That was also on my mind but its rather kinda hard for beginners like me, now I'm using jquery plugins now it's easier. Thanks though.